# Pointers and Strings in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I'm trying to write a functions to modify strings in C. 
If I have a function like

```
char *func(char *s){
    char *t=s;
    s++;     //option 1
    t++;     //option 2
    *t='a';  //option 2
    return s;
}
```

If I do something like [option 1]: `s++;` I believe it will return the pointer to wherever s is now pointing. If I do [option 2]: `t++;` and `*t='a';` then `return s`, will it return the address for the first spot of `s` but with modified contents or will it return the address with the original content?

Comment: Read a book.  There's lots of books on how C works.

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything, currently, so your question is unclear.

Comment: Books. The original internet.

Comment: One of the options is not possible (see the answers). The others, and more are possible. We haven't got enough information to give you good advice. We need more information from you about what you are tring to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I do t++; and *t='a'; then return s, will it return the address for
>   the first spot of s but with modified contents or will it return the
>   address with the original content?

I believe your question assumes something like this:

```
char s[] = "abcde";
char *t = s;
t++;
*t = 'a';
```

Here you've got one string and two pointers that initially both point to the beginning of the string. At the third line, you modify one of the pointers to point to the next character. At the fourth line, you modify the data at that location. Since `s` points to the same data, and the data is modified, the string that s points to will change.

```
printf("s is: %s\n", s");   // s is: aacde
printf("t is: %s\n", t");   // t is: acde
```

BTW, there's no better way to really learn this stuff than to write little test programs and play with them. A good book will explain how things are supposed to work, but playing with code is the way that you grow to really understand the code and believe what the books tell you.

Comment: don't you need `char s[] = "abcde"` to be able to modify it?

Comment: @steabert Yes, you certainly do. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *func(char *s)
```

In this code, `s` is a pointer to a region of memory, that (I assume) represents a string.

```
s++;
```

now `s` points to the next char, in the same region of memory, that (I assume) represents a string.

```
char *t=s;
```

Now you have *two* pointers to that region of memory.

```
t++;
*t='a';
```

Now you have changed that region of memory, replacing the second character with an `'a'`.

Therefore: if you then return `s`, you will return a pointer to that same region of memory, which was altered.  If you want to return an altered copy of the string, you have to make a copy of the memory first.

```
char *func(char *s){
    char *t=strdup(s); //duplicates a string
    s++;
    *t='a';
    free(t); //you have to free the memory from strdup at some point
    return s; //returns pointer to second character of unchanged string
 }
```

Comment: Aa you have increased the pointer `t` the `free` bit is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

In the code:

```
char *func(char *s)
{
    char *t=s;
}
```

you are missing a return statement, so garbage is returned.

The variable `s` is a local copy of whatever you passed to the function.  If you write `s++` inside the function, you change what the local pointer points at, but don't change the argument.

When you do `t++;` and `*t = 'a';`, you are making `t` point to the second character of the string passed as `s`, and then assigning the character `'a'` to that.

So, if you have:

```
char *func(char *s)
{
    char *t = s;
    s++;
    t++;
    *t = 'a';
    return s;
}
```

then the return value will be a pointer to the second character of the original string, which has been modified to contain `'a'`.

Comment: i thought that you needed a double pointer to point to a pointer. wouldn't this be the same as saying int a = b, and if I change a, b will be changed?

Comment: @chikuba: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  Yes, you would need a double pointer to point to a pointer.  But `s` in the argument list is simply a copy of a pointer, not a pointer to a pointer.  Similarly, `t` is a simple pointer.  But `*t` assigns to part of the string pointed at by `s`.  Writing `*t = 'a';` modifies the string, but not the pointer to the string.  In particular, if the call is `func(&array[4])`, then the `*t` assignment modifies `array[5]` in the calling function, without changing the `&array[4]` (which is just as well since that isn't modifiable).

Answer (score 0):

What behaviour do you need?

Both returning the initial value of s, and returning the final value of s make sense.

The one option you do not have is doing `*t='a'` but returning with the original memory unchanged. Memory is changed

Returning the original s is quite common, for example strcpy.

It is also common to return a pointer to 'the next char after the one I just modified' (which is an option you did not offer).

You need to think through, and decide what is the helpful thing for the function to do?